# Оптимизация обработчика операций с помощью массива функций

Tags: java

задачей является оптимизация двух функций

на первую из них нужно передать номер операции (целое число) и два операнда (действительные числа)
и далее с помощью оператора выбора с операндами выполнялась соответствующее действие

```
if (OperationNumber! = 0)
{
switch (OperationNumber)
{
case 1: OperationPlus (); break;
case 2: OperationMinus (); break;
case 3: OperationMultiplication (); break;
case 4: OperationDivision (); break;
case 5: OperationDiv (); break;
case 6: OperationMod (); break;

}
```

суть оптимизации заключается в замене оператора выбора на массив, элементами которого являются математические операции, то есть алгоритм предусматривает вместо выбора номера, просто вызов элемента массива с переданным номером.

вторая функция практически такая же, только на нее передается только одно число, для вычисления некоторой функции (типо Sin, Cos, Tg).

Если в Java можно организовать вышеописанную оптимихацию, то подскажите пожалуйста как создать такой массив, и каким образом проводить вызов операций / функций из него.

Если кто имеет свободную минутку, то я бы был очень признателен за помощь, поскольку только начал изучать Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// задаем интерфейс абстрактной операции
// где E задает тип обрабатываемых параметров
interface IFunction<E>
{
    public E calculate(E x, E, y); // или (E ...args)
}

реализации интерфейсов:

class AddFunction implements IFunction<Integer>
{
    public Integer calculate(Integer x, Integer y)
    {
        return Integer.valueOf (x.intValue() + y.intValue())    
    }    
}

class MulFunction implements IFunction<Integer>
{
    public Integer calculate(Integer x, Integer y)
    {
        return Integer.valueOf (x.intValue() * y.intValue())    
    }    
}

// создаем таблицу с маппингами
Map<Integer,IFunction<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,IFunction<Integer>>();
...
map.put(Integer.valueof(0), new AddFunction());
map.put(Integer.valueof(1), new MulFunction());

// использование:
public Integer test(int opcode, Integer x, Integer y)
{
    return map.get(Integer.valueOf(opcode)).calculate(x, y);
}
```

тоже самое но с использованием массива:

```
// маппинг с использованием массива:
IFunction<Integer> array = new IFunction<Integer>[2];
...
array[0] = new AddFunction();
array[1] = new MulFunction();

// использование:
public Integer test(int opcode, Integer x, Integer y)
{
    return array[opcode].calculate(x, y);
}
```

Comment: возможно кто знает как организовать этот алгоритм с помощью статического массива, так как здесь идет поиск по карте, но он не нужен потому индекс известен

Comment: суть от этого не сильно меняется, если взять что код операции это индекс в масиве тогда все вообще просто очень. сейчас исправим пример

Comment: у меня есть еще одно решение, здесь используется интерфейс и для каждой операции отдельный класс, с идентичными методами. В массив загоняется классы, а потом просто вызвать соответствующий элемент массива и выполнить его метод (который описан в интерфейсе)

пример идентичен вашему, я о исправленом варианте.

таким образом обходит предложенные мной кейсы, и избегается поиск по карте. То что мне и нужно, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: в маленьком приложении не суть важно чем вы пользуетесь массивом или мапой, производительность не так критична. в таких ситуацияк бывает удобнее пользоватся мапой чем просто массивом. ключ ведь может быть любой тип помимо банальных number/string, нести в себе другие полезные данные. напр: вместо int в данном примере можно использовать enum...

Comment: а если при разработке какого-то большого проекта программисты будут выполнять вот такие практически незначительные оптимизации, то в результате работа большого программного продукта будет оптимизирована значительным образом? или с таких малых оптимизаций, даже для большого проекта толку не будет?

Comment: В качестве курьеза вся эта груда кода вполне подойдет. Но в практических задачах за такое надо ругать. Вот в С/С++ все было бы очень даже элегантно.

Comment: надо ли ругать вместо такой конструкции Case размером в 30 проверок?

Comment: Только если эта проверка используется много-много раз в секунду. Тогда выигрыш может быть. А так - создание объектов и пр. кучу ресурсов занимает. А проверка switch - дело довольно быстрое.

Comment: сравнивать мапу и массив в любом случае бесполезно понятно что массив будет работать быстрее. мое мнение следующее: массив незначительно быстрее, а мапа удобнее. поэтому чаще всего выбираю последнюю.  
не факт кстати что в java элементы массива в памяти организованы так же как в случае с С.

p.s. может это и не пример "идеального кода", но наглядный и доступный для понимания
p.s.s есть мнение что оптимизация кода без надобности, это пустая трата времени. ни одно приложение не будет работать идеально быстро. имеют место ситуации когда потраченое время на "оптимизацию кода" не оправдывает себя

Comment: да нормальный код. и обсуждаем мы не массив и мапу, а стоит ли так вообще в данной ситуации так заморачиваться.

Comment: в данной ситуации конечно же нет. а если количестви свитч/иф возростает до нн-го количества или их количество заранее не известно, - то конечно же мапа.

лично мне нравится решение с мапой. особенно забавным оно становится если в качестве ключа для мапы выступает какой-то комплексный класс (я имею в виду сложный обьект а не просто число) с перегрузкой методов hashcode [+ equals]

Answer (score 1):

моя проблема решена, массив указателей можно использовать в С + +, а массив из обекта класса надо використаовуваты только в том случае, если поиск функции вызывается много раз в секнду. так как вызов идентификаций функции не будет выполняться так часто, я использую кейс, как мне и посоветовали форумчане.

Очень благодарен за помощь [@jmu](/users/1810/jmu)  и  [@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать массив объектов, каждый из которых содержит один метод, который принимает 2 параметра и вызывает нужную функцию, передавая ей эти параметры. Только сомневаюсь, даст ли это выигрыш.

Comment: почему вы сомневаетесь, разве так мне не удастся избежать определенного количества проверок и сэкономить процессорное время?

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю синтаксиса такой конструкции, если можете то приведите пожалуйста пример.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что создание кучи дополнительных классов-функторов тут вообще являются оптимизацией. Нельзя ли решать задачу на более подходящем для этого функциональном или скриптовом языке?

Comment: на С/С++ эта задача решалась бы элементарно при помощи массива указателей на функции.

Comment: полностью согласен, про старый добрый С все иногда забывают

Comment: задачу нельзя решать на других языках, чем JAVA, это учебное задание
а в JAVA есть возможность создать массив указателей на функции?

Comment: ну, такая возможность гипотетически есть, нужно въезжать в Java Reflection API, но это совсем не то же что указатели на функции. Вообще хочется посмотреть в глаза тому преподавателю, который такие задачки задает. Нехороший он человек.

Comment: Ну, если препод задал, то деваться некуда, надо делать...

Comment: задача - инженерный калькулятор, а задачу уникниты CASE операторы я поставил себе сам, так мне рассказали, что в С есть возможность организовать вищеписаний массив указателей. Вот я и решил организовать массив, чтобы избежать проверки. Только здесь получается массив не указателей, а классов.

Если смотреть с точки зрения профессионала, то что лучше бы было вместо такой конструкциии написать 30 кейсов?

Comment: написать 30 кейсов и не мудрить.